# ausearch to filter audit logs to show only read, write , attribute changes in file

Tags: audit, auditd

I want to filter audit logs for changes made to /etc/hosts file using ausearch (audit).
I can see multiple entries for single modify action for file in ausearch like syscall=chmod, syscall=open etc.

Please help me to understand exact filter required for confirm there is change in file or its attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you placed a file watch for writes and attribute changes? As per
`auditctl -a always,exit -F path=/etc/hosts -F perm=wa`

With this you can see who has modified the files attributes or has written to it.

To see what the change is requires some kind of file content monitoring capability.